# My selenium python test code is not throwing element not visible exception

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm newbie to selenium with python. Here I'm writing the code to test my html page(delay added), I'm expecting element not visible exception but my test code says is success and closes the browser although i have commented the tearDown() function. I'm unable to understand how this is happening? My target is to learn implicit and explicit waits with selenium python.

**Below is my selenium python test code:**

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class DemoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome("F:\Nalini_Backup\NALs\Selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("file:///F:/Nalini_Backup/NALs/Python/Selenium_Python/Workout/calc_num.html")   
        #self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_func1(self):    
        var = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/button")
        var.click()
        var1= self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='demo']").tag_name
        print var1

        self.assertEqual(var1,"p","navigator.appName property check")


    #def tearDown(self):
        #self.driver.quit()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

**Below is my HTML page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test for selenium waits</title>
</head>

<body>
<div align="center">
<h1>
<script>
    document.write("Hello World")
</script>
</h2>
</div>

<script>
    document.write("Beautiful day!!")
    if (navigator.appName == "Netscape")
    {   document.write("You are using Netscape");
        window.status = "status message is displayed here";
        <!--alert("Netscape detected");-->
    }
    else
    {
    document.write("you are not using chrome <br>");
    document.write("may be some other browser");
    window.alert("Netscape not detected");

    }
</script>

<p>Test button for browser name </p>
<button onclick="setTimeout(test,6000)"> Click me </button>
<p id ="demo"></p>
<script>
function test()
{

var x = navigator.appName
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can refer http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html to learn how webdriverwait works.

Comment: Can anyone let me know the behavior of my code: Browser is closed automatically although driver.quit() is commented and i'm expecting my code to throw error element not visible exception as i have included delay in my html script but am not getting that result. please help me to understand these two behaviors